# How to create tappered thread in OpenSCAD?

Tags: 3d-design

Is there any simple way of creating tappered thread in OpenSCAD? I need something like 10 mm in diameter at the end, 9 at the top and the height of 10 mm.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what approach you took, what you've already tried and why it failed? That might help possible asnswers to know where to start explaining.

Comment: There's plenty of libraries for OpenSCAD for creating threads. Just couldn't find any for tapered thread (i.e. pipe thread).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have contacted Dan Kirshner (the author of openscad threads library) and he has updated the library. Now it supports tapered threads. Thanks, Dan!

[Thread-drawing modules for OpenSCAD](http://dkprojects.net/openscad-threads/)

Answer (score 4):

If your math and OpenSCAD skills are superior to mine, you may be able to make use of the OpenSCAD Metric Nut, Bolt & Threads Library located here:
[OpenSCAD Metric Nut, Bolt & Threads Library](https://www.youmagine.com/designs/openscad-metric-nut-bolt-threads-library)

It uses various means to generate polygons about a radius and includes the formulae for partial revolutions. It is presumed in the design that the center of rotation for the generated polygons is constant. I looked over the code for outside thread and could easily determine the radius references.

With proper coding, you could generate a variable radius based on the height of the cylinder at a specific point and achieve the tapered effect you require.

I expect that you'd have to reduce your desired radius by a fraction, say 0.05 mm in order to embed the thread forming polygons within your tapered cylinder.

If you aren't a strong coder, disregard this answer.

Comment: So, no ready solution. Thanks for the comment. Will play with the library.